# Telethon and Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, telegram, telethon

Can I use the Telegram API with Selenium Webdriver and Java?

I want to call the TelegramClient in Webdriver. Can anyone tell me if this is possible and if so, how?

I've tried import org.telegram.api.engine.TelegramApi; then created TelegramApi TAPI; but I can't see a way to create a TelegramClient TClient.

Comment: What are you trying to do with Telegram API? I don't see any reason to use Selenium. Connect to the API with a regular HTTP client using the Telegram commands. https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples - these are some Bots examples

Comment: I'm not familiar with using a regular HTTP client, but I am familiar with Selenium. I wouldn't have a clue where to start with the Telegram bots